# Hive Queries are not executing. Showing Exceptions in CLI

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

while using Hive CLI, Even for show databases query, I am getting Exception

```
"Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
Time taken: 0.05 seconds"
```

, Recently we upgraded from `CDH 5.1.2 to CDH 5.4.1`. But it was working fine for somedays after upgradation.

And we cant find any errors in Log, The services are running good. We are using Mysql DB as metastore db,it is working fine. I tried re-installing the service also,again the same error continues.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the compression codec which we was using in 5.1.2. Later we disabled GPL Extras and forgot to change the compression codec to default. This caused the issue and it has been fixed by changing the compression codec to default.

Thanks